# Adding new columns to tables in Mysql DB using EF in c# programatically

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework

I am working on a project in VS2015 with Mysql using EF. I have a set of categories already created and sub-categories also. I need to allow users to add new categories and when they are added how do I add the new categories as new columns in the mysql db tables programatically. 
Eg. Adding new category CatNew, this will be a row in Category table. And this CatNew should be added as a new column in the Other table.

Is there a way to refresh EDMX at runtime to include new changes mysql database?
Or any other way to implement the above functionality?
Please advise.

Comment: I don't advise adding columns willy-nilly like this. That is an understatement. Come up with a better design.

Comment: It is a requirement based on the Business logic. New categories need to appear on other pages as columns and users will enter values in them.

Comment: If you think that is the way to do it, go for it

Comment: I just edited my question. I need to implement logic to allow users to add new columns and refresh EDMX at runtime or any other ways to implement the same. Thanks.